# Packages are installed in Puppet master are not installed in Puppet agent nodes

Tags: puppet

I am newbie to Puppet. As a learning path, I was trying to install a package `nagios-common`.I have used the  below Puppet manifest to install the package.

```
class pckd {
  package {'nagios-common':
    ensure => present,
  }
}

node default {
  include pckd
}
```

Also i have applied `puppet apply` on the master node. This package is installed in master successfully.

Below is the `/var/log`.

```
labcluster01node01 puppet-agent[99575]: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
labcluster01node01 puppet-agent[99575]: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
labcluster01node01 puppet-agent[99575]: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
labcluster01node01 puppet-agent[99575]: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
labcluster01node01 nagios: Auto-save of retention data completed successfully.
labcluster01node01 puppet-agent[99575]: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
labcluster01node01 puppet-agent[99575]: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I have applied `puppet agent -t` on the agent nodes and was unable to install the package on the agent node.This  package is not installed in the agent node.Added to the above query, is there a time limit to which the package get reflected.

Comment: Those logs state that your client is not successfully certifying against the CA on your master. You need to fix that first.

Comment: Sure.I will check on that.

Comment: @MattSchuchard  I tried running a shell script in agent nodes. I was successfully able to execute it. If there was a certification issue then it wouldn't have been installed in the agent nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because your master and agent are having some issues with communication, try pinging master from slave and see.

It should work fine when you add FQDN of master to the \etc\hosts file of agent.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.Like you said I have added the FQDN of master to the host files of agent